# Cannot get selected listbox

Tags: wcf, windows-phone-7, data-binding, casting, windows-phone-7.1

Here is the image I want to extract the enjoymentID

[image: The inner data details I want to extract]

I want to extract the enjoymentID from the data bounded selected item, but i tried all the way available in web still failed to extract it due to invalidCastException.

```
    private void listBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        SuperData data = (sender as ListBox).SelectedItem as SuperData;
        ListBoxItem selected = this.listBox1.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(data) as ListBoxItem;
    }
```

I tried this and also e.AddedItem[0] but still could not get it.

```
<Grid>
                <ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" Name="listBox1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" SelectionChanged="listBox1_SelectionChanged">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="132">
                                <Image Source="{Binding image}" Height="73" Width="73" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,10,8,0"/>
                                <StackPanel Width="370">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding title}" Foreground="#FFC8AB14" FontSize="28" />
                                    <!--TextBlock Text="{Binding Message}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="24" /-->
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding description}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="24" />
                                    <TextBlock Text="Test" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="24" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
            </Grid>
```

This is the UI part where i bind the data. The return from WCF is `List<REData>` data type and i just bind to the listbox with `listBox1.ItemsSource = e.Result`.

```
    public int category { get; set; }
    public int categoryField { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string descriptionField { get; set; }
    public int enjoymentID { get; set; }
    public int enjoymentIDField { get; set; }
    public string image { get; set; }
    public string imageField { get; set; }
    public object PropertyChanged { get; set; } << i don't know what is this
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string titleField { get; set; }
```

This is the content inside e.AddedItem[0] also:

[image]

Comment: What is the contents of the e.AddedItem array when the SelectionChanged event fires?

Comment: please see the print screen =D

Comment: Those are the properties of a particular type, what type is the e.AddedItems[0]? Have you tried casting the e.AddedItems[0] to that type? If that cast succeeds then you should then be able to access the underlying properties and values of those properties.

Comment: No, i couldn't and i did write a class for it to cast it into but failed. i don't know why it will become complicated while i bind 5 data into it only..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your screen shot the type of the first item of the array is RoyalEnjoyment.REServiceReference.REData, if you cast e.AddedItems[0] to this type then you should be able to gain access to the various property values.

For example, RoyalEnjoyment.REServiceReference.REData x = (RoyalEnjoyment.REServiceReference.REData)e.AddedItems[0];